# Joining or merging files in C

Tags: c, file, join, merge

I'm using Curl to download files from the internet. If a file is big, through the use of the Range header i split it in 3 chunks and i download them separately making multiple connection to the same url. Now the problem is, how do i join back those 3 different chunks into one big file? Searching on the internet all i found is merging text files using fgetc, fgets and the likes which interpret the data as text files. But my files are mostly video files or big iso files hence binary data. I looked into fwrite but how can i know which size is one element? It's just binary data. I'm confused.
The Curl routine which writes to the various chunks is this:
`size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t sz, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) { size_t written = fwrite(ptr, sz, nmemb, stream); return written; }`
Let's say i downloaded these 3 chunks, filepath1.x, filepath2.x, filepath3.x, how can i merge them into output.mp4?

Comment: Why not just write to the same file at various offsets? You wouldn't need the chunk files at all.

Comment: Can you show me some code? Which function should i use? fwrite? The argument about the size of 1 element which should be? Char? Unsigned Char? I'm new to writing files in C

Comment: Whether a file is interpreted as a text file is about how you `fopen()` it, not about what functions you use afterward to access it.  To open a file in binary mode, include a `b` in the open mode, other than as the first character.  Example: `"wb"`, `"rb+"`.  And this makes a difference in practice only on some systems, notably Windows.  On Linux and MacOS, among others, there is no practical difference between opening a file in text mode and opening it in binary mode.

Comment: So you mean if i open the file in binary mode then i can use fgets and it should not interpret it as a text file and stop at '\n'?

Comment: Have you considered not storing the chunks in separate files in the first place?  Just because you do the download in three pieces doesn't mean you can't write the pieces to the same file, one after the other.  It seems counterproductive to incur a need to merge by putting them in separate files.

Comment: @amateur, I mean that a text file is characterized by system-specific conventions that the I/O library deals with transparently to you -- mostly line terminator translation in practice, but there can be other things.  The behavior of the I/O functions is defined *on top of* that, and in that sense is the same for binary and text files.  `fgets()` is not usually what you want for a binary file, but that depends on the file.  There's nothing at all wrong with `fgetc()` for a binary file.

Comment: But perhaps what you're actually looking for is the bulk I/O functions, `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Comment: fwrite signature: size_t fwrite( const void* buffer, size_t size, size_t count,
               FILE* stream ); What should i put as the size arg? sizeof(char)? sizeof(unsigned char) perhaps? can i put an arbitrary type and then read the number of that size i want?

Comment: The `cat` command (its name is an abbreviation of concatenate) would do the job trivially.  Otherwise, `fread()` and `fwrite()` if you must roll your own. Or  `system(”cat inputs.* >output”);` perhaps.

Comment: Please don't be shy. Can you show some code with fread and fwrite? Something like this? while(fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), SZ, frptr) > 0)
                    fwrite(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), SZ, fwptr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using shell utilities anyway, the trivial way to do this is with [`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)). `cat file1.x file2.x file3.x > file.x`.

If you want to do this in pure C, use [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) but switched to read binary files. Text vs binary is only an issue on Windows. POSIX systems (Unix and MacOS) don't make a distinction.

> File access mode flag "b" can optionally be specified to open a file in binary mode. This flag has no effect on POSIX systems, but on Windows it disables special handling of '\n' and '\x1A'.

If this is just a little utility program, print to stdout and use shell piping to redirect the output to a file. Just like `cat`.

We read each file by allocating a fixed buffer, and reading and writing chunks into and out of that buffer. I like to use the [`BUFSIZ`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) constant because that's likely to be the same as the block size of your system which makes reading more efficient. 4096 is also a good value, 4k is a common block size.

[`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) are odd. Rather than just telling them how much to read, we need to tell them to read X number of Y sized objects. This is a hold over from [record-oriented filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) and most useful when you're reading a list of fixed sized objects. Since a C string is an array of 1 byte characters, we want to read 1 byte N times. Asking to read up to the size of our buffer is: `fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), f)`.

`fread` returns the number of objects read. We're reading 1 byte objects, so this is equivalent to the number of bytes. We write that amount to `fwrite`. If BUFSIZ is 4096 bytes but the file is only 50 bytes we'll only write 50 bytes, not 50 bytes plus 4046 bytes of trash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Allocate a buffer for reading.
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    // Or FILE *output = fopen(output_file, "wb")
    FILE *output = stdout;

    // Iterate through the filenames given on the command line.
    for( int i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++ ) {
        // Open the file for binary reading.
        char *filename = argv[i];
        FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if( f == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        }

        // Read a BUFSIZ chunk, write it to the output.
        size_t bytes_read;
        while( (bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), f)) > 0 ) {
            fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, output);
        }

        // Close the input file.
        fclose(f);
    }

    if( output != stdout ) {
        fclose(output);
    }
}
```